# How to find hidden div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div style="vertical-align:top;" class="ajax-upload-dragdrop">
    <span style="color: #B2B2B2;font-size: 18px; opacity: 1; margin-right:249px;" id="cv_founder">
    Upload Your CV
   </span>
        <div class="ajax-file-upload" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; cursor: default;">Browse File
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control" id="founder_cv_file" style="display: none;">Browse File</div>
    <input type="hidden" id="founder_cv" name="data[Founder][0][cv]"> <em>*</em>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
alert($(".ajax-upload-dragdrop").parent().find("div:hidden").attr("id"));  //Not work
alert($(".ajax-upload-dragdrop").parent().find("input[type=hidden]").attr("id"));  //Work fine
```

How to find hidden div in given code. I successfully find hidden input but do not find hidden div. Please Help me.

Comment: It works in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/605nqLks/), doesn't it?

Comment: What is not working, is the alert not showing or the value is wrong?

Comment: @Spokey `Not display id of div`

Comment: Ya its works in fiddle

Comment: Your problem is somewhere else, please provide more information to your question.

Comment: If your first div `.ajax-upload-dragbox` is hidden, it would return that as the first element in the set. Since it has no ID, then it would return `undefined` for that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `.parent().find()`, it traverses up to `.form-group` and then finds all `div:hidden` elements. If your div `.ajax-upload-dragbox` is visually hidden, it would return that as the first element in the set. Since it has no ID, then it would return `undefined` for that value. You want to use the [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method. This way you don't need to do any extra traversing, and it won't include the `.ajax-upload-dragdrop` element with no ID:

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/605nqLks/7/)

```
alert($(".ajax-upload-dragdrop").siblings("div:hidden").attr("id"));
```

The same will work for your `input` element, as the `:hidden` in this case refers to the `type` property:

```
alert($(".ajax-upload-dragdrop").siblings('input:hidden').attr("id"));
```

is shorthand for

```
alert($(".ajax-upload-dragdrop").siblings('input[type="hidden"]').attr("id"));
```

Comment: I was thinking of other properties, my bad.

Comment: @Sadikhasan your original code works like a charm in provided HTML aswell. Next time please provide HTML, in which your code doesn't work.

Comment: @Regent see my updated answer for why to use `.siblings()` over `.parent().find()`

Comment: @Regent `siblings()` works fine for me. I dont know without `sibling` why do not work?

Comment: @Derek Well, I have already agreed that `.siblings()` is better than `.parent().find()` in this particular situation. But once again: original code works in provided HTML example. That is what I don't like.